# where to call repository update/add methods?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository

I have a domain service and i need to create an aggregate inside it, because the logic for create this aggregate involves another aggregates and calls to repository to check some business rules.

Is it correct to call Repository.Add(newEntity) inside a domain service? or a domain service only can query entities?

Comment: Assuming: `UI -> Controller -> Business Layer -> Repository` then the BL calling Repository.Add(Entity) would be pretty normal.

Comment: @AthomSfere thanks for reply. I have the impression that only Application Services use repositories to add, update and delete aggregates, just because i only read examples of ddd codes doing this way. Maybe because those examples are simples.

Comment: I'm not sure of a few things you are saying: ddd codes? And what is your differentiation between a domain service, and an application service? A Repository is a pattern (or part of various patterns) so it can be anywhere that pattern makes sense; Be it a Windows service, a Web API, or a console application

Comment: Application Service is service at application layers which dont have domain logic. Domain Services are in domain layer, have domain logic, and are called by application services

Comment: Aw, so tiers of the hypothetical app? Then yes, you've just not seen the right examples! Look into perhaps MVVM perhaps. Where your Business layer has the logic in the ViewModel, and often the Repository is injected here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical architecture using Domain Driven Design has an Application Service which calls a method in a Repository to query the database, so the repository can create and return an instance of a domain model; an aggregate.

The domain has no knowledge of and dependencies on the repository. When constructing the aggregate root, it should contain all information in the form of entities and value objects it needs to perform it’s tasks.